# Differences between OGC and ISO WKT/WKB specification?

Tags: well-known-text, ogc, interoperability

Are the OGC-Simple feature access and the ISO (ISO/IEC 13249-3:2011 "Information technology - Database languages - SQL multimedia and application packages - Part 3: Spatial") significantly different (*different enought to justify purchasing the  ISO/IEC 13249-3:2011 PDF*)?

Comment: I think it depends on what you are doing. If you are doing conformance / compliance testing, then definitely yes. If you are using some pretty standard queries and its working for you, almost certainly not. What is the goal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are working with geometry types beyond the usual point/line/polygon/collection or are working with more than 2 dimensions, then yes, get the ISO spec. Otherwise, no. Also get the old OGC guidance on WKB for higher dimensions (or read the [PostGIS doc](http://svn.osgeo.org/postgis/trunk/doc/ZMSgeoms.txt)) in case you're worried about maximum interoperability. (For 2d and simple geometries the new ISO stuff is a superset of the old stuff (and neither of them usefully describe how to handle EMPTY geometries in WKB, in 2d or otherwise)).